# Material Dropdown Select, Keep Open After Selection

Tags: reactjs

How do I keep a Material Single Select Dropdown Open after a selection is chosen, and not close the dropdown?
It keeps Material Select open for Multi, but not single. I will happily take a solution that uses Multi, but only allows user to input at most 1 as a workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use onOpen func attribute to keep open dropdown,if you want to write close that dropdown on specific condition then use onClose func attribute.
as mentioned below


import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');
  const [keepOpen, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setAge(event.target.value as string);
  };
  const handleOpen = (event: any) => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = (event: any) => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          open={keepOpen}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: please upvote my question also, sent points, thanks